# What is the name of a phrase containing examples?

Tags: phrases

For example, in the sentences "Famous singers, like Billy Joel and Elvis Presley, are known to everyone." or "He knew many people, such as John and George, who were taller than him." what is the name of the phrases ", like Billy Joel and Elvis Presley," and ", such as John and George,"? Are they appositive phrases? Are they nonrestrictive clauses?

Answer (score -1):

I think thy are simply appositives; I wouldn't call them phrases. If you use three they are items in a series.

Comment: Doesn't the present of "like" or "such as" mean that what follows is not an appoistive?  It's not enough "ap" to be so with those intervening words.